# Unable to prevent reuse of cells in UITableViewCell: Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Every 8th row is repeating if I try to perform an action on the cell.

```
extension ExploreDetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return specificItemInfo.count

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return specificItemInfo[section].subItemArray!.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PriceCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PriceTableViewCell
        cell.configureCell1(specificItemInfo[indexPath.section].subItemArray![indexPath.row], specificItemInfo: specificItemInfo[(indexPath.section)])
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)   -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell") as! ItemTableViewCell
    cell.configureCell(specificItemInfo[section])
    return cell
}
```

Inside the cell, I'm using a button to set the value of a label. But the value set for one cell is again 8 cells below. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Reset the label each time you load the cell. So before you call cell.configureCell1. Reset the label to cell.yourlabel.text = ""

Comment: You could also override `-prepareForReuse:` on the cell subclass to achieve the same result

Comment: @RichTolley - prepareForReuse should not be used for this. Here is a quote from the official UITableView's documentation. "For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state." Here is a link - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse

Comment: @idavidov - I didn't know that - thanks for the info

Comment: Do not use a table view cell as the header.

Answer (score 1):

> Inside the cell, I'm using a button to set the value of a label

Model-view-controller! The problem is, as you say, that the cell is reused in another row. The solution is to store the new label value in the model when the button is used, so that the next time `configureCell1` is called, it pulls the right value for this row out of the model. *Never* use the cell itself for storage of anything! It is just a *view*. Store only in the *model*.